# QNetworkRequest and QUrl encoding c++

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Im trying to connect to gmail and consume the atom file.
Im having problem with passwords that contain !#$%^&* chars.

```
    pNetworkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    connect(pNetworkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), 
            this, SLOT(result(QNetworkReply*)));

    Settings settings;
    settings.load();
    QString url;

    url.append("https://");
    url.append(settings.getUserName());
    url.append(":");
    url.append(QUrl::toPercentEncoding(settings.getPassword()));
    url.append("@mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom");


    pNetworkManager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url.toUtf8())));
```

I get reply "Protocol "" is unknown"
Qt 4.8

How is this done properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you construct a `QUrl` directly?

```
QUrl url("https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom");
url.setUserName(settings.getUserName());
url.setPassword(settings.getPassword());
pNetworkManager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
```

It handles all the necessary encoding and `QNetworkRequest` takes it directly anyway. No need to mess with string encodings.